# How to count linear regression with vue.js and chart.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, linear-regression

for example, for the current data, I would like to be able to display a linear regression

I did this in vista and I would like to ask you how I can proceed with the calculation?
I don't really know how to use the formula
My html

```
<canvas id="orders_chart" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

my data

```
type: 'line',
            data: {
            labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Orders',
                    data: [1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 8, 9, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 1, 5, 5, 5, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 1, 3, 5, 9, 15],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }
            }
```

and my functions

```
mounted() {
        this.createChart()
    },

    methods: {
        createChart() {
                const ctx = document.getElementById('orders_chart');
                const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: this.type,
                    data: this.data,
                    options: this.options,
            });
        }
    }
```

For example, what should I do now?
I should just display a line on certain calculations, as far as I guess but I don't really know how I could do it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of data points (the index in array is the X coordinate while the value of the array element is the Y coordinate) then you can use the following module to apply different regression formulas over it. Then you can draw the result in the same way as your original array of data points:

```js
const DEFAULT_OPTIONS = { order: 2, precision: 2, period: null };

/**
* Determine the coefficient of determination (r^2) of a fit from the observations
* and predictions.
*
* @param {Array<Array<number>>} data - Pairs of observed x-y values
* @param {Array<Array<number>>} results - Pairs of observed predicted x-y values
*
* @return {number} - The r^2 value, or NaN if one cannot be calculated.
*/
function determinationCoefficient(data, results) {
  const predictions = [];
  const observations = [];

  data.forEach((d, i) => {
    if (d[1] !== null) {
      observations.push(d);
      predictions.push(results[i]);
    }
  });

  const sum = observations.reduce((a, observation) => a + observation[1], 0);
  const mean = sum / observations.length;

  const ssyy = observations.reduce((a, observation) => {
    const difference = observation[1] - mean;
    return a + (difference * difference);
  }, 0);

  const sse = observations.reduce((accum, observation, index) => {
    const prediction = predictions[index];
    const residual = observation[1] - prediction[1];
    return accum + (residual * residual);
  }, 0);

  return 1 - (sse / ssyy);
}

/**
* Determine the solution of a system of linear equations A * x = b using
* Gaussian elimination.
*
* @param {Array<Array<number>>} input - A 2-d matrix of data in row-major form [ A | b ]
* @param {number} order - How many degrees to solve for
*
* @return {Array<number>} - Vector of normalized solution coefficients matrix (x)
*/
function gaussianElimination(input, order) {
  const matrix = input;
  const n = input.length - 1;
  const coefficients = [order];

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    let maxrow = i;
    for (let j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
      if (Math.abs(matrix[i][j]) > Math.abs(matrix[i][maxrow])) {
        maxrow = j;
      }
    }

    for (let k = i; k < n + 1; k++) {
      const tmp = matrix[k][i];
      matrix[k][i] = matrix[k][maxrow];
      matrix[k][maxrow] = tmp;
    }

    for (let j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
      for (let k = n; k >= i; k--) {
        matrix[k][j] -= (matrix[k][i] * matrix[i][j]) / matrix[i][i];
      }
    }
  }

  for (let j = n - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    let total = 0;
    for (let k = j + 1; k < n; k++) {
      total += matrix[k][j] * coefficients[k];
    }

    coefficients[j] = (matrix[n][j] - total) / matrix[j][j];
  }

  return coefficients;
}

/**
* Round a number to a precision, specificed in number of decimal places
*
* @param {number} number - The number to round
* @param {number} precision - The number of decimal places to round to:
*                             > 0 means decimals, < 0 means powers of 10
*
*
* @return {numbr} - The number, rounded
*/
function round(number, precision) {
  const factor = 10 ** precision;
  return Math.round(number * factor) / factor;
}

/**
* The set of all fitting methods
*
* @namespace
*/
export default {
  linear(data, options) {
    const sum = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    let len = 0;

    for (let n = 0; n < data.length; n++) {
      if (data[n][1] != 0) {
        len++;
        sum[0] += data[n][0];
        sum[1] += data[n][1];
        sum[2] += data[n][0] * data[n][0];
        sum[3] += data[n][0] * data[n][1];
        sum[4] += data[n][1] * data[n][1];
      }
    }

    const run = ((len * sum[2]) - (sum[0] * sum[0]));
    const rise = ((len * sum[3]) - (sum[0] * sum[1]));
    const gradient = run === 0 ? 0 : round(rise / run, DEFAULT_OPTIONS.precision);
    const intercept = round((sum[1] / len) - ((gradient * sum[0]) / len), DEFAULT_OPTIONS.precision);

    const predict = x => ([
      round(x, DEFAULT_OPTIONS.precision),
      round((gradient * x) + intercept, DEFAULT_OPTIONS.precision)]
    );

    const points = data.map(point => predict(point[0]));

    return {
      points,
      predict,
      equation: [gradient, intercept],
      r2: round(determinationCoefficient(data, points), DEFAULT_OPTIONS.precision),
      string: intercept === 0 ? `Y = ${gradient} * X` : `Y = ${gradient} * X` + (intercept<0 ? ' ' : ' + ') + `${intercept}`,
    };
  },

  exponential(data, options) {
    const sum = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

    for (let n = 0; n < data.length; n++) {
      if (data[n][1] != 0) {
        sum[0] += data[n][0];
        sum[1] += data[n][1];
        sum[2] += data[n][0] * data[n][0] * data[n][1];
        sum[3] += data[n][1] * Math.log(data[n][1]);
        sum[4] += data[n][0] * data[n][1] * Math.log(data[n][1]);
        sum[5] += data[n][0] * data[n][1];
      }
    }

    const denominator = ((sum[1] * sum[2]) - (sum[5] * sum[5]));
    const a = Math.exp(((sum[2] * sum[3]) - (sum[5] * sum[4])) / denominator);
    const b = ((sum[1] * sum[4]) - (sum[5] * sum[3])) / denominator;
    const coeffA = round(a, DEFAULT_OPTIONS.precision);
    const coeffB = round(b, DEFAULT_OPTIONS.precision);
    const predict = x => ([
      round(x, DEFAULT_OPTIONS.precision),
      round(coeffA * Math.exp(coeffB * x), DEFAULT_OPTIONS.precision),
    ]);

    const points = data.map(point => predict(point[0]));

    return {
      points,
      predict,
      equation: [coeffA, coeffB],
      string: `Y = ${coeffA} * Exp(${coeffB} * X)`,
      r2: round(determinationCoefficient(data, points), DEFAULT_OPTIONS.precision),
    };
  },

  logarithmic(data, options) {
    const sum = [0, 0, 0, 0];
    const len = data.length;

    for (let n = 0; n < len; n++) {
      if (data[n][1] != 0) {
        sum[0] += Math.log(data[n][0]);
        sum[1] += data[n][1] * Math.log(data[n][0]);
        sum[2] += data[n][1];
        sum[3] += (Math.log(data[n][0]) ** 2);
      }
    }

    const a = ((len * sum[1]) - (sum[2] * sum[0])) / ((len * sum[3]) - (sum[0] * sum[0]));
    const coeffB = round(a, DEFAULT_OPTIONS.precision);
    const coeffA = round((sum[2] - (coeffB * sum[0])) / len, DEFAULT_OPTIONS.precision);

    const predict = x => ([
      round(x, DEFAULT_OPTIONS.precision),
      round(round(coeffA + (coeffB * Math.log(x)), DEFAULT_OPTIONS.precision), DEFAULT_OPTIONS.precision),
    ]);

    const points = data.map(point => predict(point[0]));

    return {
      points,
      predict,
      equation: [coeffA, coeffB],
      string: `Y = ${coeffB} * Ln(X)` + (coeffA<0 ? ' ' : ' + ') + `${coeffA}`,
      r2: round(determinationCoefficient(data, points), DEFAULT_OPTIONS.precision),
    };
  },

  power(data, options) {
    const sum = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    const len = data.length;

    for (let n = 0; n < len; n++) {
      if (data[n][1] != 0) {
        sum[0] += Math.log(data[n][0]);
        sum[1] += Math.log(data[n][1]) * Math.log(data[n][0]);
        sum[2] += Math.log(data[n][1]);
        sum[3] += (Math.log(data[n][0]) ** 2);
      }
    }

    const b = ((len * sum[1]) - (sum[0] * sum[2])) / ((len * sum[3]) - (sum[0] ** 2));
    const a = ((sum[2] - (b * sum[0])) / len);
    const coeffA = round(Math.exp(a), DEFAULT_OPTIONS.precision);
    const coeffB = round(b, DEFAULT_OPTIONS.precision);

    const predict = x => ([
      round(x, DEFAULT_OPTIONS.precision),
      round(round(coeffA * (x ** coeffB), DEFAULT_OPTIONS.precision), DEFAULT_OPTIONS.precision),
    ]);

    const points = data.map(point => predict(point[0]));

    return {
      points,
      predict,
      equation: [coeffA, coeffB],
      string: `Y = ${coeffA} * X ^ ${coeffB}`,
      r2: round(determinationCoefficient(data, points), DEFAULT_OPTIONS.precision),
    };
  },

  polynomial(data, options) {
    const lhs = [];
    const rhs = [];
    let a = 0;
    let b = 0;
    const len = data.length;
    const k = DEFAULT_OPTIONS.order + 1;

    for (let i = 0; i < k; i++) {
      for (let l = 0; l < len; l++) {
        if (data[l][1] !== null) {
          a += (data[l][0] ** i) * data[l][1];
        }
      }

      lhs.push(a);
      a = 0;

      const c = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < k; j++) {
        for (let l = 0; l < len; l++) {
          if (data[l][1] !== null) {
            b += data[l][0] ** (i + j);
          }
        }
        c.push(b);
        b = 0;
      }
      rhs.push(c);
    }
    rhs.push(lhs);

    const coefficients = gaussianElimination(rhs, k).map(v => round(v, DEFAULT_OPTIONS.precision));

    const predict = x => ([
      round(x, DEFAULT_OPTIONS.precision),
      round(
        coefficients.reduce((sum, coeff, power) => sum + (coeff * (x ** power)), 0),
        DEFAULT_OPTIONS.precision,
      ),
    ]);

    const points = data.map(point => predict(point[0]));

    let string = 'Y = ';
    for (let i = coefficients.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (i > 1) {
        string += `${coefficients[i]} * X ^ ${i} + `;
      } else if (i === 1) {
        string += `${coefficients[i]} * X + `;
      } else {
        string += coefficients[i];
      }
    }

    return {
      string,
      points,
      predict,
      equation: [...coefficients].reverse(),
      r2: round(determinationCoefficient(data, points), DEFAULT_OPTIONS.precision),
    };
  },
};

export { DEFAULT_OPTIONS };

export function predict(cost,reg_kind,reg_coef)
{
  if(cost<=0) return 0;
  let t = 0;
  switch(reg_kind)
  {
    case 1: // linear
      t = cost * reg_coef[0] + reg_coef[1];
      break;
    case 2: // exponential
      t = reg_coef[0] * Math.exp(cost * reg_coef[1]);
      break;
    case 3: // logarithmic
      t = reg_coef[0] + reg_coef[1] * Math.log(cost);
      break;
    case 4: // polynomial
      t = reg_coef.reverse().reduce((sum, coeff, power) => sum + coeff * Math.pow(cost, power), 0);
      break;
    case 5: // power
      t = reg_coef[0] * Math.pow(cost,reg_coef[1]);
      break;
  }
  return t <= 0 ? 0 : t;
}
```